# Replacing <base href> with a new address and HTTP Header value with NGINX

Tags: nginx, proxy

Our Angular5-cli application will be served from a webserver not directly accessible to the users. Instead, they need to access it via a security gateway/reverse proxy, used for authenticating the users. So the users visit either:

- http://proxy/app/int (for login in with a company internal user)
- http://proxy/app/ext (for login in with an external user)

So the proxy will require the users to login and then reverse proxies to our application server http://appsrv/app

**Problem:**
With `<base href="/">`, all includes and links would now point to: http://proxy/, for example http://proxy/bundle.js, which is not correct, since it should be http://proxy/app/(int|ext)/bundle.js, , 
depending on whether they logged in via /int or /ext. This int or ext is passed as a HTTP header to the webserver.

The only way I see to solve this, is to substitute `<base href="/">` with `<base href="/app/int">` if the http header==int, or `<base href="/app/ext">` if the http header==ext

- Is there any other solution?
- Can this even be done with nginx?

Comment: Did you ever find a way to use nginx to solve this problem?

Comment: @firedfly After a long time I found out that removing the `<base href="/">` tag entirely has led to all includes being relative, and therefore I had no longer any need to replace any include with nginx. So this was the solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [angular-cli](https://cli.angular.io/), then without playing with nginx configuration, you can use [`base-href`](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build#base-tag-handling-in-indexhtml) option to good effect.

Comment: Yes I'm using angular-cli, but I need to be able to set base-href dynamically during runtime and depending on the HTTP headers of the request. If I understand it correctly, what you suggested is just how to set base-href statically with angular-cli no?

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression parsing and `ngx_http_sub_module` to achieve this.

Untested but adopted from an in production setup:

```
    location /my-proxy/ {
        if ($request_uri ~* "/my-proxy/(somepath|otherpath)/(.*)") {
            proxy_pass                        https://myserver.local/$2;
        }
        proxy_set_header Host                 myserver.local;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP            $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For      $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto    $scheme;
        sub_filter                            'href="/' 'href="/$1/';
        sub_filter_once                       off;
    }
```

This will also rewrite all other absolute `href="/` paths. If that's too much you can replace the sub_filter line by a more explicit one to just replace `<base href="/` and strip out `sub_filter_once` line (`on` is default)